# Method passes an incorrect number of parameters to an SLF4J or Logj2 logging statement

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, sonarqube-scan

Sonar reports this bug: Correctness - Method passes an incorrect number of parameters to an SLF4J or Slf4j2 logging statement.

`log.info("{}", e);`

What should i do to fix it? Thanks

Comment: If `e` is an `Exception`, you shouldnt use a placeholder (`{}`) at all

Comment: @codeflush.dev Which placeholder is correct ?

Comment: None. Just `log.info("", e)`. Exceptions don't need a placeholder

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way is the following code:

```
log.info("{}", e.getMessage());
```

Comment: The stack trace cannot be recorded in this way.

Comment: @Andy Xu You can use `logger.info ("{}", e.printStackTrace ());` to print more information,in fact it is equivalent to `e.printStackTrace ();`